# allow permissions to access external sheets in cell formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a Google sheet in which has formulas `importrange` and `query` functions, accessing other external sheets.
The problem is that when I create a copy of it, this copied sheet show errors on the cells containing the formulas, requesting permission to access the external sheets.

If you click to allow permission it works but is there a way to automatically set the permissions ok when making copies of the original spreadsheet?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, no there is not. the authorization cannot be automated/skipped. each newly created spreadsheet has a new ID and that ID always need to be authorized.

Comment: Hi, I wonder whether there is a way to create in the new copied sheet a button to authorize it ( via apps script ). The reason is that the spreadsheet I am creating needs to be copied by other users, just like using just a template...